# Trying to handle Alert confirm pop up

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, alert

On my web page, we are filling form , there we are selecting `UserName` from drop-down, selecting Project from drop-down then selecting Role from radio button, then applying Role by selecting from drop-down
then clicking on apply button,

After that we are receiving alert pop up for like user is added.

I am adding Code to handle alert pop

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

I am getting below
error:-

> Assert.Fail failed. OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException:
> unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Role added successfully.}

And My Test case is failing

> (Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.86)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
> errorResponse)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
> driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot()    at
> UserManagement_Automation_Test_Suite.BaseClasses.ScreenShots.Take(String
> fileName, String floderName) in
> C:\UserManagement_Automation_Test_Suite\UserManagement_Automation_Test_Suite\BaseClasses\ScreenShots.cs:line
> 60    at
> UserManagement_Automation_Test_Suite.TestCases.TS_User_Management_0012ManageUserRoles.Action_01()
> in
> C:\UserManagement_Automation_Test_Suite\UserManagement_Automation_Test_Suite\TestCases\TS_User_Management_0012ManageUserRoles.cs:line
> 30

1. `Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();`
2. 

```
  public static void AlertPopUp()
        {
            string text = ObjectRepository.Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;
            Assert.IsTrue(text.Contains("User added successfully with email: pramod.kumar-ext@alstomgroup.com."));
    }
```

Expecting without failing I should be able to close or click on OK button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.